# what does the following line of code means in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning xslt. I am trying to understand some xslt codes, but am not getting what the following line of code means:

```
<xsl:variable name="Product" select="document('ProductList.xml')/node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[2]/node()[2]"/>
```

I can understand the variable will be "$Product", but i am unable to understand the value of the select attribute, the '/'s and nodes()[] after the document function. I have coding knowledge of c# and java and i am not familiar with this type of syntax. I would like to know what these '/'s mean in the value of the select.

Comment: Show us a bit of productList.xml, its not good practice to get the nodes values by index no., if index of nodes changes - so do ur output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `select` attribute is an indication that the variable's value should be determined by an XPath expression.

The `document('ProductList.xml')` loads the file with the name "ProductList.xml" to perform an XPath selection on it.

The `/node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[2]/node()[2]` part means that the 2nd child of the 2nd child of the 2nd child of the 1st element should be selected.  In other words, if ProductList.xml looked like this:

```
<a>              <!-- /node()[1] -->
  <b>            <!-- /node()[1]/node()[1] -->
    <c />        <!-- /node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1] -->
    <d />        <!-- /node()[1]/node()[1] -->
  </b>
  <e>            <!-- /node()[1]/node()[2] -->
     <f />       <!-- /node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[1] -->
     <g>         <!-- /node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[2] -->
        <h />    <!-- /node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[2]/node()[1] -->
        <i />    <!-- /node()[1]/node()[2]/node()[2]/node()[2] -->
     </g>
  </e>
</a>
```

Then that XPath would select the `<i>` node, which is the second child of `<g>`, which is the second child of `<e>`, which is the second child of `<a>`, which is the 1st (and only) root element.

Answer (score 0):

Reading backwards :-

```
node()[2],       node()[2],       node()[2],       node()[1],      document('ProductList.xml')           
second child of, second child of, second child of, first child of, ProductList.xml document
```